# Use Controller for Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, menu, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In an enterprise-level application, everything (well, almost) need to be configurable.  That's why I've created a Menu and Menu Item model that will allow an administrator to create multiple menus:

```
public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? MenuID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentMenuItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to give them the ability to render a specific menu in a partial view which will be rendered in a layout view, and security applied:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="sidebar-toggler hidden-phone"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form class="sidebar-search">
            <div class="input-box">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
                <input type="button" class="submit" value=" " />
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
    @foreach (var m in Model.MenuItems)
    {
        if (m.Role == null || User.IsInRole(m.Role.Name))
        {
            <li class="@(m.MenuItems != null && m.MenuItems.Count > 0 ? "has-sub " : "") @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == m.Controller || (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null && ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString() == m.Area) ? "active " : " ") ">
                <a href="@Url.Action(m.Action, m.Controller, new { area = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Area) ? "" : m.Area) }, null)">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Icon))
                    {
                        <i class="@m.Icon"></i>
                    }
                    <span class="title">@m.Name</span>
                    @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == m.Controller || (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null && ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString() == m.Area))
                    {
                        <span class="selected"></span>
                    }
                </a>
                @if (m.MenuItems != null && m.MenuItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    <ul class="sub">
                        @foreach (var mi in m.MenuItems)
                        {
                            if (mi.Role == null || User.IsInRole(mi.Role.Name))
                            {
                                <li class="@(ViewBag.Title == mi.Name ? "active" : "")">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action(mi.Action, mi.Controller, new { area = mi.Area })">@mi.Name</a>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

To test my current code, I hard-coded a menu ID in the layout view:

```
<div class="page-container row-fluid">
    <div class="page-sidebar nav-collapse collapse">
        @Html.Partial("_LeftMenu", new MyAppContext().Menus.Find(1))
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, a couple of issues have cropped up, First, I need to be able to pass a menu ID to the partial so it will render the proper menu.  By using the partial view method, I don't know of a way to accomplish this goal.  Second, when I applied security to the menu that was being loaded, the menu items are being displayed in the opposite order.  So, by having a controller of some type to perform the data logic for the menu and layout, it should solve this problem.

So, anyone have any suggestions as to what direction I need to go in?  I'm beginning to think that my attempt at using a partial view for the menu (being dynamic) is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly calling @Html.Partial you can have a controller with action method and use  @Html.RenderAction in place of @Html.Partial method.
In the action method you can pass the id and also apply the security logic which you need and in the view just iterate through the menu collection and show the required menus.
This will keep your UI also clean.

Comment: I think I have it: `@{ Html.RenderAction("UserMenuAction", "Menu", new { area = "Admin", id = 1 }); }`, but now I have a problem.  I was selecting the "active" menu item based on the Controller and/or Area of the page.  Now, the menu always returns the Admin area because that is the controller that is being used (`ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()` and `ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]`).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Well I don't think you can use that logic for selecting the menu item.You may want to add state of the selected menu to may be session or add to ViewBag and use that to show active menu item.There are other better ways of doing this but it depends on how the specific project is organized.

Comment: I ended up passing the Area, Controller, and Action into the UserMenuAction from the _Layout and it works great!  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.